# Focused animation on custom JDialog

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

If a [`JFrame`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) has a [`JDialog`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) modal open, the `JDialog` is `animated` (the borders and title bar have a lighter colour) if any other part of the application is clicked other than the `JDialog` with focus. The user is made aware of the window in focus to attend to first.

I have a Swing application with custom dialogs, `setUndecorated(true)` and custom title bars.

Is it possible to implement the behaviour described above for these custome dialogs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of blinking the window, i used a lighter color on the glass pane when the dialog is open.

Answer (score 2):

This flashing is done by the window manager, Java doesn't even get called so there's nowhere to hook into.
It is platform specific too - on Linux I can grab the underlying frame and move it around - there's no animation.